# Qsort Comparison Function

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, sorting, qsort

I am a beginner to C and I am trying to understand the comparison function needed for the qsort function.

### Part One: Syntax

A simple suggested use is this (I have included some main() code to print the results as well):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = { 40, 10, 100, 90, 20, 25, 12, 13, 10, 40 };

int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const int *ia = (const int *)a; // casting pointer types 
    const int *ib = (const int *)b;
    return *ia  - *ib; 
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    for (n=0; n<10; n++)
    {
        printf("%d ",values[n]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    qsort(values, 10, sizeof(int), compare);
    for (n=0; n<10; n++)
    {
        printf("%d ",values[n]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why you need all the extra things in the compare function so I simplified it to this:

```
int compare (int *a, int *b)
    {
        return *a-*b; 
    }
```

This still works, and produces the same results. Can anyone explain to me what I removed, and why it still works?

### Part Two: Why Pointers?

Additionally, do I really need to use pointers? Why can't I just compare "a" and "b" directly like so (this does NOT work):

```
int compare (int a, int b)
        {
            return a-b; 
        }
```

For some reason, with a multidimensional array, I was able to get away with NOT using pointers and for some reason it worked! What is going on? (Example code of sorting a multidimensional array by the 2nd item in each sub array):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[7][3] = { {40,55}, {10,52}, {100,8}, {90,90}, {20,91}, {25,24} };

int compare(int a[2], int b[2])
{
    return a[1] - b[1];
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    for (n=0; n<6; n++)
    {
        printf("%d,",values[n][0]);
        printf("%d ",values[n][1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    qsort(values, 6, sizeof(int)*3, compare);
    for (n=0; n<6; n++)
    {
        printf("%d,",values[n][0]);
        printf("%d ",values[n][1]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I am really glad the multidimensional array sorting is working as that is my **end goal** anyway, but I have no idea how I managed to get it to work (other than dumb luck and chopping up the code) so I would really love some explanation as to why some of the examples I provided work, and why some don't!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> This still works, and produces the same results. Can anyone explain to me what I removed, and why it still works?

You are invoking undefined behavior in C. See C99 6.3.2.3 Pointers/8:

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another
>   type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted
>   pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the pointed-to type,
>   the behavior is undefined.

In C++, this program is flat-out ill-formed: http://ideone.com/9zRYSj

It still "happens to work" because the `compare` function expects a pair of pointers; and on your particular platform `sizeof(void*)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`, so calling a function pointer of type `int(void *, void *)` which in fact contains a pointer to a function of type `int(int *, int *)` is *effectively* the same as the pointer type casts on your particular platform at this particular point in time.

> Additionally, do I really need to use pointers? Why can't I just compare "a" and "b" directly like so (this does NOT work):

Because `qsort` takes a general comparison function for any two types; not just `int`. So it doesn't know what type to which the pointer is dereferenced.

> For some reason, with a multidimensional array, I was able to get away with NOT using pointers and for some reason it worked! what is going on!

This is because the following prototypes are the same:

1. `int foo(int *a, int *b);`
2. `int foo(int a[], int b[])`

That is, an array *decays* into a pointer when passed to a function. Explicitly specifying the length of the array as you did:

```
int foo(int a[2], int b[2])
```

causes the compiler to make `sizeof` and other compile time bits to treat the item as a two element array; but the function still accepts a pair of pointers when it gets down to the machine level.

In any of these cases, passing a comparison function that does not take a pair of `void *`s results in undefined behavior. One valid result of "undefined behavior" is "it just seems to work". Another valid result would be "it works on Tuesdays" or "it formats the hard disk". Don't rely on this behavior.

Comment: It is interesting that arrays break down into pointers. Is this something to be relied on, or is there an inherent error in this as well? How would you suggest modifying the multidimensional sorting to make it reliable?

Comment: @Dlinet: Always make your comparison function take `const void*`. Cast that pointer to `const int*`. Then use `operator[]` as you usually would.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why you need all the extra things in the compare
>   function so I simplified it to this

Whether you use `const` qualifier is up to you. You are expected to not modify the values in the comparator. But it's possible to cast away the `const` and break the promise you make to the compiler.

---

**[qsort](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/qsort.3.html)** expects a function pointer which takes two `const void *` as parameters which is why pointers are passed for the comparator function:

```
   void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                  int(*compare)(const void *, const void *));
```

So passing `a` and `b` would lead to interpreting the *values* as pointers which is obviously wrong.

---

It works without passing pointers for multi-dimensional arrays because when you pass arrays, they decay into pointers. So the following comparator you have is ok.

```
int compare (int a[2], int b[2])
{
    return a[1] - b[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple : From the manual of qsort  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html  the prototype of the function pointer is :

```
int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
```

The typedef associated with this prototype can be declared this way

```
typedef int (*comp_qsort_funct_t) ( const void *, const void * )
```

Where `comp_qsort_funct_t` is the type of the function pointer

The prototype of the compare function of qsort is using const variable because this is a good practice / design since the data is not going to be modified.

Using a different prototype may lead to unexpected result depending of the compiler / platform. Or just fail to compile, example provided in comment : http://ideone.com/9zRYSj

So you shall not use a different prototype.

Comment: This is C, not C++. In C++ this is completely illegal; not just "bad design practice" http://ideone.com/9zRYSj

Comment: I was just explaining why the prototype is using const variable... I don't understand your point about C++ here ... Please explain

Comment: In C, this code is undefined behavior. In C++, this code is flat out ill-formed. Your reference is to a C++ source, but you're speaking about C. Please clarify that difference and I'll change the -1 to a +1.

Comment: The link provided is about C and not C++... Did you just read the domain of the URL ?
And the code provided is *not*  ill-formed, this is this way a function prototype is declared in C

Comment: The prototype is not ill-formed; the call to `qsort` is. You pointed at a page that says "C++ Reference" in the title and content of the page; but this is an area where C and C++ differ significantly; so just substituting in a C++ reference may be confusing to readers.

Comment: @BillyONeal Your answer is exactly what I was trying to explain, but I was not using the right word... I edited mine to prevent any confusion / allusion about C++  let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21783/discussion-between-benjarobin-and-billy-oneal)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to confirm the observations of Dlinet who asked the original question.

The C compiler will indeed accept all the forms of the compare function, even without const, and even using int * instead of void *. However, my C++ compiler rejects the variations and only accepts the const void * form.

The C compiler even accepts the int form not using pointers at all. I checked and found that the int form of compare function is receiving *pointer* values, not the ints of the array. And the result is that the array is not sorted but remains in the same order. And I think all this is what you would expect.

Thus, seems that you could use int * instead of void * in the function definition, and then would not need to cast within the function.

Whether this is good programming practice is moot, with some programmers saying yes and some saying no. Seems to me, good programming or not, the reduction of clutter would be a point in favor of using int * instead of void *. But then, a C++ compiler does not let you do that.

Comment: I don't understand how this late answer got an upvote; this is completely wrong. C compilers accept all kinds of code that is illegal. The C code in question causes undefined behavior. This is _not_ good programming practice, and nobody who knows how to program in C says that it is.