# A C program that sorts Hurricanes by name or year

Tags: c, file, sorting

I need to write a program that loads data from a file with Hurricane data (like year, name, states affected)
 The data file looks like this:
 
1960 Dnna Fl,NC
1972 Agnes FL
1969 Camile MS
The user will be able to select whether the hurricanes are sorted by year or name. The sort function should keep the year list and affected states list parallel with the hurricane names. Allow for a max of 30 hurricanes, but use constant macro for this number to permit easy future expansion of the database.
Here is what they want the output to look like if sorted by years.
Year Name States
1960 Donna FL,NC
1969 Camille MS
1972 Anges FL
I Think i'm not going about this problem right. I just can't figure out how to sort the array and print it. Every time I just try to print the array to make sure it is loaded with the right data, I just get a bunch of junk, or it just crashes.
Here is the code that has worked best (if you can call it that)
 so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define Numof_Hurricane 23

char Hurrican_data[Numof_Hurricane][3];
char temp[Numof_Hurricane][3];

int i,j;
char HowSort;

int cmp ( const void *pa, const void *pb ) {
    const char (*a)[4] = pa;
    const char (*b)[4] = pb;
    return strcmp(*a, *b);
}
// start of program
int main()
{

    FILE *Hurrican;
    Hurrican = fopen("hurricane_data.txt","r");   // the data file for Hurricanes 
    if (Hurrican==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: File failed to open\n");
        fclose(Hurrican);

    }
    for(i=0; i<30; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            fscanf(Hurrican," %s", &Hurrican_data[i][j]);    //loads data into array
        }
    }
    fclose(Hurrican);
    printf("How would you like to sort the data?\n"
            "(by Year or Name, use Y for year and N for name)");   // ask how user wants to sort it
    scanf(" %c", &HowSort);
    if (HowSort == 'Y'|| HowSort == 'y')                                     //sort by year
    {
        printf("\nYou chose to sort by year");
//I plan on adding a function here to sort by year

// my atempt to sort by year
     qsort(Hurrican_data, 1, sizeof Hurrican_data[0], cmp );

// To print sorted data
      for ( i = 0 ; i < Numof_Hurricane ; i++ ) 
      {
        for ( j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%s ", Hurrican_data[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
        else
        {
            printf("\nYou chose to sort by name");
// I plan to put a function here to sort by Name
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a start, you use `strncmp` to compare string in c.  (https://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp). Then there are plenty of articles about sort e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059510/qsort-comparison-function

Comment: There is no memory allocated to the pointer arrays you use.

Comment: C universal sorting function is called `qsort()`. Unless you are unhappy with its performance (and for only 30 hurricanes, you should not), there is no reason not to use it instead of implementing your own sorting routine.

Comment: Fyi, `if (HowSort == 'Y'||'y') ` doesn't do what you think. It will always evaluate as *true* because `'y'` is a non-zero value. You need those comparisons individualized: `if (HowSort == 'Y' || HowSort == 'y')`. It's just how the language works. If your compiler doesn't warn you about this, you probably need to turn up your warning levels.

Comment: You would benefit from creating a `struct` to hold info on each hurricane. That would allow creating a simple compare function that you could pass to `qsort` to complete the entire year/name sorting in a 1-line call. Well worth investigating.

Comment: thanks @WhozCraig I always forget that or I forget the ==.

Comment: thanks @DavidC.Rankin you are right. I have just started to try and learn `struct`, but i kept running into a few problems while trying to fill it with data from the file. That is why I thought I should try and see if I can do it with an array. With the array I was able to get my program to run farther then with `struct`, so I thought maybe it is easier (as everyone can see, I was wrong).

Comment: The best advise anyone can give for learning C is simply to *slow down*, there is a lot there. No other language gives you the level of control you get with C (aside from assembler). Take it a step at a time, use the *man pages*, always compile with warnings enabled (e.g. with `-Wall -Wextra` in your compile string) and do not accept code until it compiles without warning or error. You can learn a lot of C simply by reading and correcting problems your compiler is telling you about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the things wrong in this code:

**Incorrect `fclose` invoke**

```
if (Hurrican==NULL)
{
    printf("ERROR: File failed to open\n");
    fclose(Hurrican); /// HERE
}
```

That `fclose` makes no sense, and is a recipe for a crash. You just determined the result of the `fopen` was NULL. Therefore, the file *didn't open*. Therefore, the file pointer isn't something you can close. There is no reason to continue the program if the file fails to open:

```
if (Hurrican==NULL)
{
    perror("hurricane_data.txt: ");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

---

**The array sizes are wrong.**

Given that your data looks like this:

```
1960 Dnna Fl,NC
1972 Agnes FL
1969 Camile MS
```

and your loader loop tries to read this content into this:

```
#define Numof_Hurricane 23

char Hurrican_data[Numof_Hurricane][3];
```

using this loop:

```
for(i=0; i<30; i++) // HERE: 30??? What about that 23 ??
{
    for(j=0; j<3; j++)
    {
        // HERE: Each of these can be no longer than TWO chars wide.
        fscanf(Hurrican," %s", &Hurrican_data[i][j]);
    }
}
```

This assumes there are always exactly 30 items in the file, which the assignments clearly states is *possible*, but not *precise*. *"Allow for a max of 30 hurricanes..."* means there could be thirty, but there could also be one, five, and even *none*. Really pouring salt on the wound, you're looping to thirty (overflowing buffers along the way, more on that below) on a core array of arrays that is only **23** elements wide. If there were thirty elements, you breach your primary array at the twenty-fourth line.

Further, your loader look is (a) unchecked, and (b) a recipe for buffer overflow on each read. Consider the very first string value on the very first line, `1960`. That string is *four* characters long; five including the terminator, yet you're trying to shove it into a buffer only *three* characters wide.

---

**Broken Sorting Algorithm**

Your sorting loop is sorting the first *character* of the names. This is wrong.

---

**A Different Approach**

The algorithm is simple:

- Define a *structure*, `Hurricane`, that holds three fields

  - `year` - a simple integer
  - `name` - a char buffer of reasonable length
  - `states` - a char buffer capable of holding a sufficient number of state abbreviations with comma separators.
- Your overall data array is a sequence of up to thirty of these structures.
- Read the data from the file one *complete* line at a time. A line length of 256 characters should be sufficient to hold the data.
- For each line parse out the year, the name, and the list of strings.
- Store these in the structure array as a complete entity.
- Use this structure array for sorting operations.

The resulting code would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_DATA        30
#define MAX_NAME_LEN    64
#define MAX_STATES_LEN  151

struct Hurricane
{
    int year;
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    char states[MAX_STATES_LEN];
};

struct Hurricane data[MAX_DATA];


void print_data(const struct Hurricane ar[], int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        printf("%d %s %s\n", ar[i].year, ar[i].name, ar[i].states);
}


void sort_year(struct Hurricane ar[], int size)
{
    int swapped = 1;
    while (swapped && size--)
    {
        swapped = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        {
            if (ar[i].year > ar[i+1].year)
            {
                swapped = 1;
                struct Hurricane tmp = ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[i+1];
                ar[i+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}


void sort_name(struct Hurricane ar[], int size)
{
    int swapped = 1;
    while (swapped && size--)
    {
        swapped = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<size; ++i)
        {
            if (strcmp(ar[i].name, ar[i+1].name) > 0)
            {
                swapped = 1;
                struct Hurricane tmp = ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[i+1];
                ar[i+1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}


// start of program
int main()
{
    int count=0, i;
    char line[256];
    char HowSort;

    FILE *fp = fopen("hurricane_data.txt","r");   // the data file for Hurricanes
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: File failed to open\n");
        fclose(fp);
    }

    // read until we are full or no more data
    for (i=0; (i < MAX_DATA && fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)); )
    {
        if (sscanf(line, "%d %63s %150s", &data[i].year, data[i].name, data[i].states) == 3)
            ++i; // only increment if we got good data
    }

    // save the number of successful reads.
    count = i;

    // close the file
    fclose(fp);


    printf("How would you like to sort the data?\n"
           "(by Year or Name, use Y for year and N for name)");   // ask how user wants to sort it
    scanf(" %c", &HowSort);
    if (HowSort == 'Y'|| HowSort == 'y')
    {
        printf("\nYou chose to sort by year");
        sort_year(data, count);
    }
    else if (HowSort == 'N' || HowSort == 'n')
    {
        printf("\nYou chose to sort by year");
        sort_name(data, count);
    }
    print_data(data, count);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I didn't have the chance to test this, but it is probably very close to what you're trying to to. The sorting algorithm in both cases is a simple bubble sort. For a real-world equivalence we would create appropriate `qsort` comparison functions and use the standard library, especially if the number of elements was significantly larger than a few dozen. For our purposes here, however, this is sufficient. See the documentation and examples of [`qsort()` **here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Most importantly, note that by using a structure to hold a record rather than splaying it across a sequence of character buffers, you not only get the benefit of proper types (`int` for the year, for example), you get better data management, and above all, *much* easier swapping of elements in the sorting routines (structure value swapping ftw).

Anyway, that's what I think you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to put the `fclose()` in the error check to see if file open. It the same thing with for loop that has the 30. I had to change some of the code to get it to work for me. the for loops is not letting me have an initial declarations, but i got it to work and from the few test I ran it work great. I do have a question if you used `typedef struct` would you not have to typed `struct hurricane`?