# Sort string alphabetically with upper case letters before lower case letters in C

Tags: c, string, sorting, uppercase, lowercase

How to sort a string in C alphabetically with upper case letters before equivalent lower case letters.

Example:

```
input:  baBadxD
output: aaBbDdx
```

Comment: I suggest using [`qsort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zes7xw0h.aspx).

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/QEgiN0)

Comment: Is there a possibility that the string contains something other than the alphabet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qsort Comparison Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059510/qsort-comparison-function)

Answer (score 3):

The necessary comparison function isn't very complex.  You can case-convert the character and compare them. If they're unequal, use the `(x > y) - (x < y)` idiom on the case-converted values to return the value.  If they're equal, use the same idiom to compare the unconverted characters.

The code does assume that upper-case alphabetic characters come before lower-case ones in the code set.  It uses an assertion to ensure that — it could be a `static_assert()` to produce a compile-time error instead of being a run-time error.  If you need to worry about accented characters, you need more complex comparisons, if only to ensure that áàäâå etc are grouped together.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)
{
    unsigned char c1 = *(unsigned char *)v1;
    unsigned char c2 = *(unsigned char *)v2;
    unsigned char u1 = toupper(c1);
    unsigned char u2 = toupper(c2);
    if (u1 != u2)
        return (u1 > u2) - (u1 < u2);
    return (c1 > c2) - (c1 < c2);
}

int main(void)
{
    assert('A' < 'a');
    char sample[] = "baBadxD";

    printf("Unsorted [%s]\n", sample);
    qsort(sample, strlen(sample), sizeof(char), comparator);
    printf("Sorted   [%s]\n", sample);

    char buffer[4096];
    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
    {
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        printf("Unsorted [%s]\n", buffer);
        qsort(buffer, strlen(buffer), sizeof(char), comparator);
        printf("Sorted   [%s]\n", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The test code sorts the sample data given in the question, and then reads more lines of data and sorts each of those.  Given a random text generator, some sample output is:

```
Unsorted [baBadxD]
Sorted   [aaBbDdx]
Unsorted [PvpxixCDvgnkLHQLlBvsJzgQLDmBxUeIhyUMvDiVpjCYvOshnaEvupb]
Sorted   [aBBbCCDDDEeggHhhIiiJjkLLLlMmnnOPpppQQssUUuVvvvvvvxxxYyz]
Unsorted [rvnsnRcQGUGDyydxrvIhYkQemsqfNtafIZlVQqHvDxkLnxdQouwBrv]
Sorted   [aBcDDddeffGGHhIIkkLlmNnnnoQQQQqqRrrrsstUuVvvvvwxxxYyyZ]
Unsorted [XZPIDAxazwWQZhxuCVotQPzTHsCQULaEiSPLAQUlnqrBiz]
Sorted   [AAaaBCCDEHhIiiLLlnoPPPQQQQqrSsTtUUuVWwXxxZZzzz]
Unsorted [NoAsbAzTWivuxSHjBKnGeDxgmWdwNESTZmZauGvmdchoGjMAAEufcZneoWWWN]
Sorted   [AAAAaBbccDddEEeefGGGgHhijjKMmmmNNNnnoooSSsTTuuuvvWWWWWwxxZZZz]
Unsorted [zcmMqAkXYXrmObgDsloVxVLfmXclNGBmDfrtVEcgHVZlRaycjbnYbSQkS]
Sorted   [AaBbbbccccDDEffGggHjkkLlllMmmmmNnOoQqRrrSSstVVVVXXXxYYyZz]
Unsorted [DHvDBHSsTgAjBaZGCXniiBqzSNkNqgeKStXzDDswSfCcJnJJSAKsmhz]
Sorted   [AAaBBBCCcDDDDefGggHHhiiJJJjKKkmNNnnqqSSSSSsssTtvwXXZzzz]
Unsorted [MGKtMuBlwdXTjysBPDhHntdGvsjRPOWlGvKTCTs]
Sorted   [BBCDddGGGHhjjKKllMMnOPPRsssTTTttuvvWwXy]
Unsorted [ChNiqW]
Sorted   [ChiNqW]
```

Comment: Much simpler indeed, but assumes `'A' < 'a'` and letters are in alphabetical order in the character set.  One less test with this: `if (u1 != u2) return (u1 > u2) ? 1 : -1;`

Comment: I think all the comparators shown so far assume the `A` sorts before other letters.  I did note that accented characters would be a problem for this code.  Yes, the code can be simplified as you suggest.

Comment: ASCII and the ISO-Latin-x character sets follow this rule (`'A' < 'a'`) but MacRoman does not for some accented characters and EBCDIC does not even for regular roman characters.

Comment: EBCDIC has lower-case letters in the (non-contiguous) range 0x81..0xA9, and the upper-case letters in the (non-contiguous) range 0xC1..0xE9.  That's one of the reasons I added the assertion — and mentioned static assertions.  Wikipedia suggests that [MacRoman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman) matches ASCII for the unaccented letters.

Comment: Yes, MacRoman only has the problem for some of the accented letters, which may or may not be handled by the `<ctype.h>` functions. I found a simple fix to get rid of the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `qsort` function with an appropriate comparison function. Such a function must be carefully crafted to implement a transitive ordering function. A collective effort from Vlad, Jonathan and I lead to this simple and portable implementation:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmpletters(const void *p1, const void *p2) {
    unsigned char c1, c2, u1, u2;
    c1 = *(const unsigned char *)p1;
    c2 = *(const unsigned char *)p2;
    if (c1 == c2)
        return 0;
    u1 = toupper(c1);
    u2 = toupper(c2);
    if (u1 != u2)
        return (u1 > u2) ? 1 : -1;
    return isupper(c1) ? -1 : 1;
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[] = "baBadxD";

    printf("before: %s\n", buf);
    qsort(buf, strlen(buf), 1, cmpletters);
    printf("sorted: %s\n", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this algorithm can also be implemented with a lookup table unless the type `char` is very large.

Comment: That seems like a complicated comparison function.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: yes, Vlad wrote a simpler one. The only advantage of this one is too group all letters before any other symbols. But even for that, it is too complicated.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I simplified your function and made it work without the `'A' < 'a'` assumption.

Answer (score 0):

What is needed is to write the comparison function carefully and use the C standard sorting function `qsort` declared in the header `<stdlib.h>`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>   

int cmp_char(const void *lhs, const void *rhs)
{
    unsigned char c1 = *(const unsigned char *)lhs;
    unsigned char c2 = *(const unsigned char *)rhs;

    if (c1 == c2)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( ( toupper(c1) < toupper(c2) ) || 
        ( toupper( c1 ) == toupper( c2 ) && isupper(c1) && islower(c2) ))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "baBadxD";

    puts(s);

    qsort(s, strlen(s), sizeof(char), cmp_char);

    puts(s);
}
```

The program output is

```
baBadxD
aaBbDdx
```

Comment: Nice and simple! I would add the optional `return 0;` at the end of `main()` for complete portability. upvoted.